# Entity Framework Profiler System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, entity-framework-4.1, profiling

When I try to run my asp.net mvc application with Entity Framework Profiler I get a `NotSupportedException`

> Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection

Did anyone have the same problem? When I start my application without this profiler, it works fine.